# Crear archivo de texto : error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator"

Tags: java, android-studio, archivo, android-sqlite

Necesito crear un archivo .txt en una ruta específica que yo creé y escribirle datos que se encuentran en mi BD dentro de ese archivo, la forma que he encontrado es OutputStreamWriter, pero me manda un error que dice:

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ejemplo/ejemplo/ejemplo contains a path separator"

A lo que he investigado es porque el método OutputStreamWriter no debe contener separadores, en ese caso ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?, ya que forzosamente necesito poner el archivo en la ruta que le especifico y escribir los datos, este es mi código:

```
String CARPETA_PRINCIPAL = "MiCarpetaPrincipal/";
String CARPETA_DOCTXT = "MiCarpetaSecundaria";
String DIRECTORIO_TXT = CARPETA_PRINCIPAL + CARPETA_DOCTXT;  

editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_nombreArchivoExportar);
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view_rutaTxt);  

public void exportarTxt(View view){
        accessPermission();
        String nombre_archivoPro = editText.getText().toString();
        if (!nombre_archivoPro.isEmpty() || !nombre_archivoPro.equals("")){
            File miFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DIRECTORIO_TXT);
            boolean isCreada = miFile.exists();
            String nombreArchivo = "";

            if (!isCreada){
                isCreada = miFile.mkdirs();
            } if (isCreada){
                nombreArchivo = nombre_archivoPro + ".txt";
            }

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DIRECTORIO_TXT);
            if (!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            String nombre_completo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + DIRECTORIO_TXT + File.separator + nombreArchivo;

            File outputFile = new File(nombre_completo);
            if (outputFile.exists()){
                outputFile.delete();
            }

            try {
                OutputStreamWriter archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre_completo, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
                AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "miBD", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor fila = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery
                        ("select codigo, cantidad from tablaDeMiBD", null);
                while (fila.moveToNext()) {
                    archivo.write(fila.getString(0) + ", " + fila.getString(1) + "\n");
                }
                archivo.flush();
                archivo.close();
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("Error", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Archivo exportado Correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textView.setText(nombre_completo);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Rellena el nombre del archivo que deseas antes de continuar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Humberto, openFileOutput no acepta separadores "/", te recomiendo usar FileOutputStream  y OutputStreamWriter utilizando la variable "outputFile", con eso funcionará adecaudamente, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error seguramente se produce en esta linea:

```
  OutputStreamWriter archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre_completo, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

El problema es que `openFileOutput()` no acepta separadores, por esta razón el error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ejemplo/ejemplo/ejemplo contains a
>   path separator

Te sugiero usar `FileOutputStream` y `OutputStreamWriter`, este sería el cambio:

```
  try {
            //OutputStreamWriter archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre_completo, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));

            /*------------------------------*/
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);
            OutputStreamWriter archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            /*------------------------------*/

            AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "miBD", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor fila = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery
                        ("select codigo, cantidad from tablaDeMiBD", null);
            while (fila.moveToNext()) {
                archivo.write(fila.getString(0) + ", " + fila.getString(1) + "\n");
            }
            archivo.flush();
            archivo.close();
   } catch (Exception e){
     //Log.i("Error", String.valueOf(e));
     Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
   }
```